# JavaScript custom confirm function without libraries

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to make custom confirm function without libraries.
The function shows modal window and buttons that returns `true` or `false`

```
if(getConfirmation) {
    do something
} else {
    do something
}
```

Everything is done except working with buttons. The problem I have that I can not stop code execution the way default `confirm` function works. I receive `undefined` or `Cancel` right after I click on the button (`Click me`) (line 56) that has to execute `getConfirmation` function.

```
const button = document.querySelector('#abc')
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // usage
    if(getConfirmation(options)) {
        console.log('Ok')
    } else {
        console.log('Cancel')
    }
})
```

The code looks like this and I think the problem in the way I detect clicks.

```
function getConfirmation(options) {
    const element = createElement('confirm_window')
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', getTemplate(options))
    document.body.appendChild(element)
    
    element.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const result = options.buttons.find(b => b.name === e.target.name).result
            document.body.removeChild(element)
            return result
        })
    })
        
}
```

Question: how can I wait until I get any click on buttons (`Confirm` or `Cancel`)?

Demo is here: https://codepen.io/hamper_/pen/eYzNXqN?editors=1010

Comment: If you want to use `async`/`await`, where it the promise that should fulfill when the button is clicked?

Comment: Honestly I don't get how to detect clicks on buttons in `async/await` way, I tried some ways, but couldn't solve it. That's why I'm here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code a little bit and use a Promise

```
function getConfirmation(options) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const element = createElement('confirm_window')
        element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', getTemplate(options))
        document.body.appendChild(element)

        element.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                const result = options.buttons.find(b => b.name === e.target.name).result
                document.body.removeChild(element)
                resolve(result);
            })
        });
    };      
}
```

```
    getConfirmation(options)
        .then(result => {
            if (result) {
                console.log('Ok')
            } else {
                console.log('Cancel')
            }
        });
```